# {{ oauth_token }} shows up and works in source but not on the page

Tags: javascript, python, django, hyperlink

I have written a view to produce an oauth_token to embedded via template syntax into a link to produce an authorization url.  When I click on the link on the page the address is missing the oauth_token.  However when I click on the link in the source it works perfectly fine and takes me to the authorization page.

What is happening here?

This is my link with template syntax:

```
<a href="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token={{ request_token }}" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=','1377808978328','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;">Or use scoring and settings from your yahoo league!</a>
```

Here is what the link looks like in the source:

```
<a href="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=q2sasyz" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=','1377808978328','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;">Or use scoring and settings from your yahoo league!</a>
```

Just to reiterate when I click on the source link I get to where I need to go but when I click on the page's link I get a message from chrome saying:

`Oops! Google Chrome could not find https`
`Did you mean: https:­/­/­api.­login.­yahoo.­com/­oauth/­v2/­request_auth`

Thanks for viewing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in the `onclick` part of the `a` tag, see the url begins with `http://https:`:

```
http://https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=
```

If you are clicking the link on the page, `onclick()` is executed. If you are clicking the link in the page source - `href` is used and the link there is valid.

Comment: Good catch!  Also as I note when I put the token after the second link it goes to where I want it too.  Thank you for your help